# Wordpress. Loop does not working in template file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created custom template and added page using this template.
But Loop does not working correctly there: Loop returns article with page id (which doesnt exists obviously).
Can anyone give an advice about that?

Header.php I used in my custom template (Loop works correct on index.php with this header):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/ptsans.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/ptserif.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/neucha.css" />    
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if( wp_title('', false) ) { echo ' |'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Loop is basic too:

```
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <div class="entry-conten clr">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links clr">', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                <footer class="entry-footer">
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit Page', 'wpex' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
            </article><!-- #post -->

            <?php comments_template(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you calling wp_footer() anywhere?  And you really should be using wp_enqueue_style instead of pasting in the css includes at the top of the file.

Comment: thank you for reply, I will use wp_enqueue_style from now. Yes, I'm using a wp_footer() on this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong. Page technically is a post (check the_ID() in dashboard), with different template. In fact you can use the same code. Maybe just tag  is not best idea for pages. to test try simplest loop

```
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); the_content(); endwhile; // THE LOOP ?>
```

Comment: Ok, I've got that. I've tryed to use your snippet and got the same result - only 1 post in loop. How can I get all posts in this case?

Comment: just build a second normal wp query with args., and add another loop to display them